# Handle form submission in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a web form to let user enter some information and submit. I want such behavior that if the submission is successful, the it will go to a page. But if there are some form submission errors (in my case is due to existing ID), I want the form stay there without going to the next page and alert the user "ID already exists". I used jQuery to handle the success and fail events:

```
function checkForm() {

$.post("/myapp/rest/customer/created", $("form").serialize(), function(
    data, status) { })
.done(function() {alert("post success");})
.fail(function() {alert("post error");});
return false;
}
```

My form is:

```
<form action="/myapp/rest/customer/created"
    onsubmit="return checkForm();" method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Customer name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer ID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id" name="id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer DOB:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br /> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After submission, no matter whether the submission is a success or failure, I only see the popup message box saying "post success" or "post error". But it will never go to the next page if it's successful. I even tried a different approach like the code below but it didn't work either:

```
function checkForm() {
    $.post("/myapp/rest/customer/created", function(data, status) {
      if (status === "success") {
        alert("post success");
      } else {
        alert("post error");
      }
    });

    return false;
}
```

So how to correct it to make it redirect to the next page (`/myapp/rest/customer/created`) if the submission is successful?

Comment: You're always returning false.

Comment: @j08691: I can't return true/false based on the status because it will always direct to the next page if I do so.

Comment: The return false is just fine. You just need to redirect the user with window.location.href...

Comment: @tonga - why not? if you return false you cancel the submit.

Comment: @j08691: It won't block in case of error if you use that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect within your success conditional using `window.location.href`:

```
if (status === "success") {
  window.location.href = 'http://url.com'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I used this approach and it works. But...after the submission is successful, it shows an error page: HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed. What causes that problem?

Comment: That means whatever URL you are redirecting to doesn't allow GET.

Comment: I used "POST" method for the submission. Previously I saw the correct page if the submission is correct.

Comment: The redirect method and the form method are separate. Can you manually go to the URL without the error?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually go to the URL"? In the jQuery post, the first argument is the URL I want to post, right? So in case of success, should it redirect to that URL specified in the `$.post()`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31954/discussion-between-matthew-blancarte-and-tonga)